# Accessing index in multidimensional arrayDeque

Tags: java

I have a multidimensional arrayDeque and I have a method that is get(i) that return index i out of the whole array. So, say i have this arrayDeque

[[0,1,2],[3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12],[13,14]];

get(7) should return 7 using some simple math operation

Comment: Doesn't ArrayDeque only have getFirst and getLast methods?

Comment: `arrayDeque.stream().flatMap(ArrayDeque::stream).limit(7).reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null)`